# Write the negation of the following logical expression: ∀,∈ℝ,∃∈ ℕ,(−)<0

Tags: logic

Write the negation of the following logical expression: ∀,∈ℝ,∃∈ ℕ,$(−)^$<0

Wouldn't the answer to this be ∃,∈ℝ,∀∈ ℕ,$(−)^$ $\geq$ 0?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: It's correct, but you did not intend the exponent n, right? Because your earlier statement has n as a multiplicand, not an exponent.

Comment: Your guess is correct. On the Stack Exchange network, you may provide an answer to your own question and perhaps even get it upvoted.